# Bind function to button in ListView using delegate in model

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to bind a function in each item of my collection to a button for that item. My collection is a `List<AssessmentItem>`, where each `AssessmentItem` is the following:

```
public class AssessmentItem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public string ResourceURL { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Icon { get; set; }
    public RunFixer Fixer { get; set; }
}
```

`public RunFixer Fixer` is the delegate I want to bind to the button for that particular `AssessmentItem`. Here is the `DataTemplate` I'm using to accomplish my plans:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AssessmentListTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="64" Height="64"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How do I bind the `<Button>`'s `Click` handler to my `RunFixer` delegate? I tried `{Binding Fixer}`, which didn't work. I also changed `Fixer` to a `MouseButtonEventHandler`, but that didn't work either.

Thank you for your time looking at this! I don't mind being educated.

---

**Additions**

The `RunFixer` delegate is declared with

`public delegate void RunFixer();`

---

**Final Code**

For my personal documentation and for other's satisfaction, I'm posting the result that worked well for me:

```
public class AssessmentItem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public string ResourceURL { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Icon { get; set; }
    public RunFixer Fixer { get; set; }
    DelegateCommand _fixerCommand = null;
    public ICommand FixerCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fixerCommand == null)
            {
                _fixerCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => Fixer());
            }
            return _fixerCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `DataTemplate`:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AssessmentListTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Command="{Binding FixerCommand}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="64" Height="64"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind a function to a button. But you can bind command object to a button's Command property. In order to do this you need to modify your class:

```
public class AssessmentItem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public string ResourceURL { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Icon { get; set; }
    public RunFixer Fixer { get; set; }
    ICommand _fixerCommand = new UICommand();
    public ICommand FixerCommand {
        get
        {
            _fixerCommand = _fixerCommand ?? new DelegateCommand<object>((o)=>
                       {var f = Fixer;
                         if(f != null) f();}); 
            return _fixerCommand;}
        }
}
```

I'm using DelegateCommand class which is a part of [Prism library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611.aspx) which can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4922)

Then you're modifying your data template to bind to this FixerCommand property

```
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Command ="{Binding FixerCommand}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="64" Height="64"/>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used a combination of yours and LordTakkera's suggestions for my code. I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind the "Click" event of a button because it is not a dependency property (in this case it is a routed event). Luckily, WPF gives us the "Command" property (which is a dependency property) for a button!

Your binding will look like:

```
Command="{Binding RunFixerCommand}"
```

Your data object will expose an `ICommand` property which will return a command object that calls "RunFixer". A great example of a reusable and easy to use generic command class can be found in [this](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) blog post.

Sample (in your AssessmentItem class):

```
public ICommand RunFixerCommand {get; private set;}

public AssessmentItem()
{
   RunFixerCommand = new DelegateCommand((p) => RunFixer());
}
```